# Is it possible to run Appium IOS test cases using grid on different user accounts of same machine

Tags: ios, grid, appium

I am able to run my IOS automated cases using grid on different machines , but i am trying now to run on different user accounts of same machine, but not able to solve this getting below error , so is it possible , have anybody tried.

```
 An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 
Error: Killing process 28794 failed: Operation not permitted
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode9 now supports multiple simulators and [Here](https://github.com/saikrishna321/AppiumTestDistribution) a pretty good example of this. This works for Sims as well as Devices.